# Acquire a custom view's xml id

Tags: android

I have a custom view `ZoneSwitchItem` (extends LinearLayout) which I use in a fragment layout xml.

From inside the custom view, I need to get the id that was assigned to it in the fragment xml. So I use `attrs.getIdAttribute();` but it returns `null` instead of the expected id `zone1`.

I could add a custom attribute `ZoneSwitchItemId` but would like to avoid that if I could use the default id attribute.

The usage in the fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.android.common.ZoneSwitchItem
        android:id="@+id/zone1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardPadding4x"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:zoneItemStyle="ArmourFont_HeadlineBig" />

    ...
```

The custom view:

```
public class ZoneSwitchItem extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView itemValue;
    private TextView itemTitle;

    public ZoneSwitchItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public ZoneSwitchItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZoneSwitchItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    private void init(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.zone_switch_item, this);

        itemValue = findViewById(R.id.itemValue);
        itemTitle = findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ZoneSwitchItem, 0, 0);
            try {
                if (typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ZoneSwitchItem_zoneItemStyle) != null &&
                        typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ZoneSwitchType_zoneItemImage).equals("ArmourFont_HeadlineBig")) {
                    itemValue.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.ArmourFont_HeadlineBig);
                }
            } finally {
                typedArray.recycle();
            }
        }

        final String id = attrs.getIdAttribute(); // <<== returns null
        itemValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnZoneSwitchItemClickedEvent(id));
            }
        });
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        float alpha;

        if (selected) {
            alpha = 1.0f;
        } else {
            alpha = 0.5f;
        }

        itemValue.setAlpha(alpha);
        itemTitle.setAlpha(alpha);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an odd method I'd not seen before, but if you check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html#getIdAttribute()), it explains that it's equivalent to `getAttributeValue(null, "id")`, where `null` is being passed for the namespace. That's where the problem is. The `android:id` attribute is in the `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` namespace. If you remove the `android:` prefix, you'll get what you're expecting, but that's not very helpful. Instead, you could call `getAttributeValue()` directly with the correct namespace.

Comment: However, that'll likely not return what you want, either. `getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId())` should be the given resource name, I believe.

Comment: @MikeM. `getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId())` did the trick!
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @MikeM. i just heard you got it, why not turn it into an answer?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Yep, I was going to. :-) I just wanna check on my assumptions about `getAttributeValue()` first, when I can get to my dev machine.

Comment: @MikeM.hmm , yeah i think with appropriate namespace (as you already suggested) it will work though since OP has confirmed , you can post the answer (with extra into , along with note or something) and update the rest later, , rest your choice, i will have to come back otherwise

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Actually, I think `getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id")` will return the integer ID in string form, rather than the actual name, 'cause aapt replaces those references in the XML directly, IIRC. I did something similar in a custom `View` a while ago, but I want to make sure I'm remembering correctly, before I put together a proper answer. I don't think anyone else will poach my answer in the meantime. That'd be pretty low. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for the `AttributeSet#getIdAttribute()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html#getIdAttribute()) states:

> Return the value of the "id" attribute or null if there is not one. Equivalent to getAttributeValue(null, "id").

The first parameter in [the `getAttributeValue()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html#getAttributeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is the namespace for the attribute. This is where the problem is, as `null` signifies no namespace, but the `android:id` attribute is in the namespace that the `android` prefix represents – `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/androi‌​d`.

This means that the `getIdAttribute()` method will only return the value for an `id` attribute with no prefix. That is:

```
<com.android.common.ZoneSwitchItem
    id="@+id/zone1"
    ... />
```

I'm not sure how useful this method is, since, with the example above, it will actually return the complete string there (`@+id/zone1`), you'd still have to have a separate `android:id` attribute to get the `View` properly assigned an ID, and Android Studio will certainly complain that the attribute lacks a namespace prefix.

The first solution that might come to mind is to simply call `getAttributeValue()` directly, and pass the correct namespace.

```
String id = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id");
```

However, this will return the integer ID value in string form, prepended with `@`, as it seems that aapt directly substitutes that value in the XML during its processing.

The actual, simple resource name can be obtained from `Resources`, with its `getResourceEntryName()` method, and the `View`'s `getId()` method, since the ID will be set in `View`'s constructor during the `super` call. For example:

```
String id = getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId());
```

Comment: Thanks for an informative and thorough answer, Mike. The `getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId());` returned exactly what I needed. Thumbs up!